# AsyncTask takes too much time the first time it executes

Tags: android, android-asynctask

The first time the Asynctask executes takes **30 or more seconds**. It happens when I enter the activity. After that, subsequents call to the Asyntask(when I enter the activity again from the previous activity) takes only 4 or 5 seconds, which I consider to be "acceptable".

Here is the code where I execute the AsyncTask

```
  @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location!=null) {
            mlastLocation=location;

            double latitud=Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getStringExtra("latitud").replace("Latitud:", ""));
            double longitud=Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getStringExtra("longitud").replace("Longitud:", ""));
            LatLng origen= new LatLng(latitud,longitud);
            LatLng destino=new LatLng(mlastLocation.getLatitude(),mlastLocation.getLongitude());
            if (mCount==0) {
                FillVariablesAsyncTask tareaAsincrona = new FillVariablesAsyncTask();
                tareaAsincrona.execute(origen, destino);

                mCount++;
            }

        }
    }
```

And here the code of the AsyncTask, where onPostExecute updates members variables and update the UI.

```
 private class FillVariablesAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng,Void,Document>{


              @Override
        protected Document doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
                  md=new GMapV2Direction();
                  LatLng origen=new LatLng(params[0].latitude,params[0].longitude);
                  LatLng destino=new LatLng(params[1].latitude,params[1].longitude);
                  Document doc = md.getDocument(origen, destino, GMapV2Direction.MODE_WALKING);
                  /*mUbicacionActual = md.getStartAddress(doc);
                  mDuration=md.getDurationText(doc);
                  mDistancia=md.getDistanceText(doc);*/
                  return doc;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) {
            super.onPostExecute(doc);
            mUbicacionActual = md.getStartAddress(doc);
            mDuration=md.getDurationText(doc);
            mDistancia=md.getDistanceText(doc);
            if (mUbicacionActual!=null && mDistancia!=null && mDuration!=null) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnIr.setEnabled(true);
                tvOrigenLatitud.setText("Latitud:"+String.valueOf(mlastLocation.getLatitude()));
                tvOrigenLongitud.setText("Longitud"+String.valueOf(mlastLocation.getLongitude()));
                tvDestino.setText("Destino:" + getIntent().getStringExtra("info").replace("Info:", ""));
                tvDestinoLatitud.setText("Latitud:" + getIntent().getStringExtra("latitud").replace("Latitud:", ""));
                tvDestinoLongitud.setText("Longitud:" + getIntent().getStringExtra("longitud").replace("Longitud:", ""));
                tvOrigen.setText("Origen:" + mUbicacionActual);
                tvDistancia.setText("Distancia:"+mDistancia);
                tvTiempo.setText("Tiempo:" + mDuration);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried out **.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)** but the app crashes. I've tried out also with a **handler** but it shows the same Behaviour, the first time takes 30 seconds or so, while the subsequents takes only a few.

Edit to show to points where i added log:

```
if (mCount==0) {
                FillVariablesAsyncTask tareaAsincrona = new FillVariablesAsyncTask();
                mStart=System.currentTimeMillis();
                Log.i("START_BEFORE_EXECUTE", mStart + "");
                tareaAsincrona.execute(origen, destino);
                long end=System.currentTimeMillis();
                Log.i("ELAPSED_EXECUTE", ((end-mStart)/1000) + "");
                mCount++;
            }
```

Here :

```
protected Document doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
                  long end;
                  end =System.currentTimeMillis();
                  Log.i("ELAPSE_PRE_BACKGROUND",((end- mStart)/1000)+"");
                  md=new GMapV2Direction();
                  end=System.currentTimeMillis();
                  Log.i("ELAPSED_POS_GMAPV2DIR",((end- mStart)/1000)+"");
                  LatLng origen=new LatLng(params[0].latitude,params[0].longitude);
                  LatLng destino=new LatLng(params[1].latitude,params[1].longitude);
                  end=System.currentTimeMillis();
                  Log.i("ELAPSED_PRE_GETDOCUMENT",((end- mStart)/1000)+"");
                  Document doc = md.getDocument(origen, destino, GMapV2Direction.MODE_WALKING);
                  end=System.currentTimeMillis();
                  Log.i("ELAPSED_POS_BACKGROUND",((end- mStart)/1000)+"");
                  /*mUbicacionActual = md.getStartAddress(doc);
                  mDuration=md.getDurationText(doc);
                  mDistancia=md.getDistanceText(doc);*/
                  return doc;

        }
```

and here:

```
      long end=System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.i("ELAPSED_onPostExecute",((end-mStart)/1000)+"");
        mUbicacionActual = md.getStartAddress(doc);
        mDuration=md.getDurationText(doc);
        mDistancia=md.getDistanceText(doc);
        end=System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.i("ELAPSED_POST_FILLVARS",((end-mStart)/1000)+"");
        if (mUbicacionActual!=null && mDistancia!=null && mDuration!=null) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnIr.setEnabled(true);
            tvOrigenLatitud.setText("Latitud:" + String.valueOf(mlastLocation.getLatitude()));
            tvOrigenLongitud.setText("Longitud" + String.valueOf(mlastLocation.getLongitude()));
            tvDestino.setText("Destino:" + getIntent().getStringExtra("info").replace("Info:", ""));
            tvDestinoLatitud.setText("Latitud:" + getIntent().getStringExtra("latitud").replace("Latitud:", ""));
            tvDestinoLongitud.setText("Longitud:" + getIntent().getStringExtra("longitud").replace("Longitud:", ""));
            tvOrigen.setText("Origen:" + mUbicacionActual);
            tvDistancia.setText("Distancia:"+mDistancia);
            tvTiempo.setText("Tiempo:" + mDuration);
            end=System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.i("ELAPSED_POS_onPostExecute", ((end - mStart) / 1000) + "");
        }
```

this image shows the log output, it shows 3 but in reality is 30 or more.
[IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/95o1ef.png[/IMG]

Comment: Does it take 30 seconds before the AsyncTask actually starts, or lasts `doInBackground()` 30 seconds? I actually suspect the first is happening...

Comment: What line is taking the most time?

Comment: I don´t know how to trace the application, if you tell me how i will do it. I only know that the UI takes a lot to update.

Comment: You can use the `Log` class and see the logs printed in the LogCat in your IDE: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: @Carlos Hernández use System.currentTimeMillis(); to track the time in doInbackground its takes.Also we should not perform long running task in asynctask this is not what asynctask are made for instead use IntentService if the time of exceution in doInBackground is too high.

Comment: 08-11 14:13:00.784  12584-14550/com.carlos.googlemapstest I/ELAPSED_BACKGROUND﹕ 25 , 8-11 14:12:35.444  12584-12584/com.carlos.googlemapstest I/ELAPSED_EXECUTE﹕ 0

Comment: it takes 25 seconds for the doInBackground and 0 in AsyncTask.execute(). I ´ve edited my answer to show you where i put logs.

Comment: [AsyncTask - Order of execution](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) : Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution. - Are there other AsyncTask-s that are executed before FillVariablesAsyncTask executes?

Comment: The method onLocationChanged, where i execute the AsyncTask, updates each 500 miliseg roughly, but i added the mCount variable  so that only one time tareaAsincrona.execute(origen, destino) gets executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time is taking have absolutely nothing to do with `AsyncTask` or `Thread` or `Handler` or `Executor`

The issue is that library you're using really takes that long to make calls to a server, or to process the information and I don't believe there's much you can do about it. It's only the 1st time because I'm guessing the library caches the result, but it still have nothing to do with the threading model you use.

The main point of my answer is that you're asking the wrong question. The correct question is:

- Why this library is taking that long to process and what can you do to shorten it?

Unfortunately the only possible way to answer it is by analysing the source code of it or talking directly with the library developer.

**edit:**

to help you measure the executions:

```
   public static class TimeMeasure {
      private final DecimalFormat format;
      private final double start;
      private final String tag;

      public TimeMeasure(String tag) {
         this.format = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
         this.start = System.currentTimeMillis();
         this.tag = tag;
         log("start);
      }

      public void log(String message) {
         double elapsed = ((double) (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)) / 1000.0;
         Log.d(tag, format.format(elapsed) + ": " + message);
      }
   }
```

then during `doInBackground`

```
protected Document doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
   TimeMeasure tm = new TimeMeasure("Carlos");
   // execute something:
   tm.log("action 1");
   // execute next
   tm.log("action 2);
   // etc... 
}
```

Comment: the line with class GMapV2Direction seems to be executing fast. Or what library do you mean?

Comment: I would guess it's either the constructor (`new GMapV2Direction()`) or the method `getDocument(...)`. But I've seen from the commands that you're also having issues properly measure those executions. Maybe first fix those, then you can be sure about what's taking that long.

Comment: yes i am having problems measuring the executions, the result seems to be inconsistent

Comment: I've added some code to help you measuring it. Unless you know precisely which call is taking that long, you won't be able to properly narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your class, here have my results: http://subefotos.com/ver/?b867eaf0fa24bccc2af7a8c0ddc1ef08o.png

Comment: from what I understood from your logs: `getDocs` is taking 11 seconds. And it's taking 50 seconds to get the location. `OnLocationChanged` only get called after 50 seconds. That's probably because you're requiring to be GPS and you're indoors maybe, or something like that.

Comment: I thought that onLocationChanged gets called every 500milliseconds, according to the parameter i set (mLocationRequest.setInterval(500);), but know i think it gets called only if there is a movement in the phone. That could be the reason for the 50 seconds. And for the 11 seconds perhaps should i rewrite de class GMapV2Direction with another Http client. Thank you very much for your help Budius.

Comment: the 500ms is `IF` there's location available and that is a very big if due to how location services works. Try to imagine the device is reading a signal from satellites in the space and triangulating the position based on the difference of signals. Yeah, it's that complex! A pleasure to help and feel free to mark as correct if you believe it was.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet so here you go: you can use your IDE's debugger after you place breakpoints on every line in the two given blocks of code to see which line takes the most to execute. Then post your findings.

Comment: i updated my question with logs. I have the code on GitHub in case someone wants to test it.

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer mentioned it is actually the library that takes too much  time.

I had a similar problem a while ago, I remember that after debugging what causes the problem was distance and duration and also if you were getting some kind of an address, it will contribute to the delay
(For Example) getting street name, city name and country etc..

I didn't really find any better `API` or library to deal with this but what i did was something to improve the user experience:

1-start another `AsyncTask` from `onPostExecute()` that will get duration and distance.

2- while the app is getting duration and distance don't block the user interface with a progress dialog or progress bar, just put loading... as an default value of your `TextView` then when the app receives the data `setText` to the actual value.

3-Do all of you data manipulation later after setting important data.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The duration and distance are calculated very fast together with the address in onPostExecuted with the methods getDurationText and getDistanceText, therefore i don´t see the need for another AsyncTask there, if i have understood you well. The problem is as you say the library. I will try to make an attemt to write it with json and another http client.